# How do I remove deleted pipeline from triggering on pull request in Azure Devops Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've been playing around with setting up validation for pull requests and now I can't fully remove unnecessary pipeline. I've deleted it under project/Pipelines tab. But when I create new pull request I can't merge it. Said pipeline still appears under *"checks"* with *"deleted pipeline name not run"*. Said pipeline can also still be found under "Deleted pipelines".

I've tried setting `pr: none` in underlying `.yml` file, removing said `.yml` file, adding `[skip ci]` in title. I can't find anything in policies tab for the project or organization. I am an admin on project if that changes anything. Is there anything else I could do?

Edit: Using Azure Devops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using GitHub, go to your repo > settings > Branches > Branch protection rules > your protected branch > edit > Status checks that are required

Remove the status check that no longer runs.

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned. Using Azure devops.

Comment: same basic idea - branches > your branch > branch policies > remove offending build check (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thank you! I would've never found it myself without reading the whole azure devops documentation.